# Ember unknown injection ajax

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on my own ember addon and I'm trying to use ajax request as follows (component):

```
ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

ajaxRequest(method, href, type, json,callback) {
  let ajax = this.get('ajax');
  let promise = ajax.request(href, {
    method: 'POST',
    data:  json
  });
  promise.then(() => {
   callback();
  }).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e);
  });
},
```

But i get :

> ember.debug.js:2307 Uncaught Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:api'

```
DEBUG: 
-------------------------------
Ember      : 2.9.1
Ember Data : 2.10.0
jQuery     : 3.1.1
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you install ember-ajax addon in your project. do you have entry for `ember-ajax` in `package.json` file

Comment: i installed - ember install ember-ajax in my package.json in devDependencies --> "ember-ajax": "2.5.3", –

Comment: try the below step `rm -rf node_modules bower_components tmp` and 
`npm install && bower install` for clean fresh installation dependancies

Comment: i found this step in the web but is not working. is it necessary to say that i#m working on my own addon?

Comment: check this [link](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addons-depending-on-other-addons). you need to specify it in `dependencies` not in `devDependencies`

Comment: Did you restart `ember s`? Can you show us your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

If your addon depends on another addon, install it as a dependency in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ember-ajax": "^0.7.1"
}
```

[Reference](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addons-depending-on-other-addons)